# How to create custom HTML elements declaratively?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I am trying to create custom elements declaratively but having trouble with it. I [read](http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/#custom-element-section) [so](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/) [many](http://pomax.nihongoresources.com/index.php?entry=1364168314) [docs](http://robdodson.me/blog/2013/03/17/why-web-components/), but they all seem outdated or insufficient because of the super new and changing technology. Does any know how to fix this? The current context (`this`) does not have `register` and I also not able to update the template. Am I on the right track?

```
<my-date><my-date>

  <element name="my-date">
    <template>
      <style>
        div {
          color: red;
        }
      </style>
    </template>
    <script>
      this.register({
        prototype: {
          createdCallback: function() {
            this.innerHTML = new Date();
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
```

http://jsbin.com/oGUKeyU/3/

Comment: what is `register` supposed to be

Comment: To register the new custom element I think. I see these in various blogs and docs. I even tried registerElement like document.registerElement. I am trying to add new Date() to the output by attaching to the createdCallback.

Comment: This link `http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/` appears to be working fine for me? Did you see the demo as well https://html5-demos.appspot.com/hangouts ? If you go through the sources you can see how they did it.

Comment: But it is using Google Polymer, I'm trying to do it via Canary without a library to see how it's done.

Comment: Is <element> broken in the spec? http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2013JulSep/0287.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TruMan1 is absolutely correct. Declarative element registration with `<element>` was [put on hold](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2013JulSep/0287.html) in the spec because of some complicated timing issues.

What will probably happen is that [Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org/) will iterate through several different timing models, sets of lifecycle methods, etc., until developers and browser vendors find a good solution to the problems listed on the mailing list above. *Then* native `<element>` registration will be re-visited.

Answer (score 1):

You try use [lifecycle HTMLElement API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/#lifecycle):

```
var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

proto.createdCallback = function() {...};
proto.attachedCallback = function() {...};

var XFoo = document.registerElement('x-foo', {prototype: proto});
```

In your case it will be like this:

```
var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

proto.createdCallback = function () {
    this.innerHTML = (new Date()).toString()
};

var xMyDate = document.registerElement('x-my-date', {
    prototype: proto
});
var newDateElement = new xMyDate();

alert(newDateElement.innerHTML);
```

But this works only in Canary.

Comment: But this is doing it via JavaScript where I'm trying to do it declaratively within the <element>...</element> tag. Should I be able to use the context somehow?